# problem with method init of view controller class

Tags: iphone, sdk, init

I try to run programm (http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/calculator-application-in-iphone/) from here, but i have problem with init method. While running programm don't creates variables (current, previous). Where is it call init-method in xCode?

Comment: That tutorial isn't very well written, you might want to look at some others.

Comment: ok, could you give tutorial with correct init-method?

Comment: Scrap that, that tutorial is terrible, pretend you never read it and forget everything you've learned from it. I haven't used any tutorials in a couple years, but http://appsamuck.com/ seems to have a few simple tutorials that might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

the init method is never called because the ViewController is loaded from a nib file.
You could move those 3 lines into `viewDidLoad`. But to be honest, I think it's better when you trash the project and look for something better. Because this is not the only problem of the project.
If you learn with these "tutorials" you will have huge problems later.
That guy has obviously never heard about memory management.

But if you want to try, add this method to the `@implementation` of `calciViewController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    operator=0;
    current =[[NSString stringWithString:@"0"]retain];
    previous =[[NSString stringWithString:@"0"]retain];
}
```

Comment: Any reason for the super artificial stringWithString: method when a constant @"0" would do?

Comment: maybe you can recommend me step by step tutorials better, thanks a lot

Comment: @Egor have you seen [CS193p](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/) from Stanford? It's available on [Itunes U](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/cs193p-student-final-projects/id395605774?i=90218598) for free. Download are available on the [stanford website](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2010-fall) I learned iPhone SDK with their first course they published on iTunes U. And from what I've heard the course is even better today.

Comment: There are also amazing books available. So if you can afford $28 for an ebook ($40 for the printed version) I would suggest you to get [Beginning iPhone 4 Development: Exploring the iOS SDK](http://apress.com/book/view/143023024X)

Comment: maybe these are not step-by-step tutorials. But imho such tutorials are not the best way to learn. I used them, and whenever I tried to leave the area of the tutorial I struggled. You can't learn programming by reading commented code without some backgrounds.